# Way to download/decode .torrent files?

Tags: python

Is there a way to download all of the chunks or contents from a Torrent file In python?

say i had a torrent file with contents

song1.mp3
song2.mp3
song3.mp3

how would i download these files?

Comment: http://fileformats.wikia.com/wiki/Torrent_file

Comment: I have no idea if you want to decode the torrent file itself, decode the contents of the torrent file, or download the files referenced by the torrent file.  Explain.

Comment: There are too many torrent downloaders. What's wrong with them?

Comment: Its part of my larger project and it needs to download torrent files...if there is a torrent downloader that i can control with python that would work too

Answer (score 2):

You can use a python client.

The last version of the original Bittorrent client is available via Sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/p/bittorrent/code/

There is also Bittornado as a pure python client:

http://www.bittornado.com/